# how to compile spring-boot-maven-plugin without version number?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to generate spring boot executable jar

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And I am getting files like this one "auth_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", but I need to get "auth_service.jar", how can I do this?

Comment: See solution of Andy Wilkinson..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference documentation for Spring Boot’s Maven plugin contains [an example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-name.html) of how to do this:

> If you need the repackaged jar to have a different local name than the one defined by the artifactId attribute of the project, simply use the standard `finalName` as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...
>   <build>
>     <finalName>my-app</finalName>
>     <plugins>
>       ...
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>repackage</id>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>repackage</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>         ...
>       </plugin>
>       ...
>     </plugins>
>     ...
>   </build>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```
>
> This configuration will generate the repackaged artifact in `target/my-app.jar`.